# Creating custom regressor model in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression, customization

I would like to create a custom regression model using scikit learn.
I'm struggle with how to return value from predict function.  Here is some code that I progressed.  I aim to use it with cross_val_score but it shows error in Temp.

```
class custom_regressor(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):  
    def __init__(self, intValue=0, stringParam="defaultValue", otherParam=None):
            self.intValue = intValue
            self.stringParam = stringParam
            self.differentParam = otherParam 

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        A1 = -3.37306
        A2 = -0.073254
        B1 = -5254.56
        B2 = 8.91515
        C = 618.225

        self.values = []
        A = A1 - A2*np.log(X['Pressure']+14.7)
        B = B1 - B2*np.log(X['Pressure']+14.7)
        RVP = np.exp(A-B/(X['Temp']+C))
        values = RVP
            #{v: i for i, v in enumerate(np.unique(Y))}
        self.values.append(values)
        return self.values
```

Here is the error:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) 18 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2897                 return
>   self._engine.get_loc(key)    2898             except KeyError:
>   -> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2900
>   indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance) 
>   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Temp'

Comment: Seems like `X` doesn't have a column called `Temp`. Use `X.columns` to see what are the available columns in `X`.

Comment: Tried X.columns and found that the column name 'Temp' is there. Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'TEMP', 'Pressure', 'CONDY', 'TOTAL CONDY', 'year',
       'month', 'day'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: TEMP, instead of Temp. 